# Performance metric for math tasks

Tags: mathematical-statistics, psychometrics, model-evaluation, item-response-theory

I have several math items which are varying in terms of difficulty. The difficulty ranges from zero to one, where zero is the most difficult one. Let's say users are solving such math tasks. I would like to compute a performance score for each user over all math items. As variables I have the difficulty of each item as well as the time the user had to solve the task and the time the user had available to solve the task (the time is limited for each task) as well as if the task was correctly solved or not.

How could a performance score look like? Perhaps Item Response Theory could help but I'm not sure.

Comment: "...as well as the time the user had to solve the task and the time the user had available to solve the task " - how are those different?

Comment: Do users all have the same amount of time to solve each task, or are some users given more time than others?

Comment: @Ben The time was limited for each task, so for example for task 1 the maximum available time was 60s with a difficulty of 0.2, for task 2 40s with a difficulty of 0.6 and so on. All users have the same amount of time available for each task. But of course users need different time to solve the tasks, for example user 1 needs 50s to solve task 1 (from the available 60s) and 40s from the available 40s for task 2 (because he was not able to solve it) and user 2 needs 59s for task 1 and 20s for task 2 etc.

Comment: ¿Can you share more about the purpose of a metric such as this?  In particular, I am wondering what time has to do with the assessment of performance.  IRT allows one to assign an "ability" score, where it is assumed that ability is a random variable across individuals.  However, speed could also be its own variable...and it may be the case that an "slower" writer takes longer to answer while they may actually have a higher ability rating.  (Thus, my question about the overall purpose.)